# Implementing momentum weight update for neural network

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I'm following along mnielsen's online [book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html). I'm trying to implement momentum weight update as defined [here](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#sgd) to his code [here](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py). The overall idea is that for momentum weight update, you don't directly change weight vector with negative gradient. You have a parameter `velocity` which you set to zero to begin with and then you set hyperparameter `mu` to typically `0.9` .

```
# Momentum update
v = mu * v - learning_rate * dx # integrate velocity
x += v # integrate position
```

So I have weight w and change in weight as `nebla_w` in the following code snippet:

```
def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
        """Update the network's weights and biases by applying
        gradient descent using backpropagation to a single mini batch.
        The ``mini_batch`` is a list of tuples ``(x, y)``, and ``eta``
        is the learning rate."""
        nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        for x, y in mini_batch:
            delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)
            nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
            nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
        self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                        for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
        self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                       for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]
```

so in the last two lines you update `self.weight` as

```
self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
```

for momentum weight update I'm doing the following:

```
self.momentum_v = [ (momentum_mu * self.momentum_v) - ( ( float(eta) / float(len(mini_batch)) )* nw) 
                   for nw in nebla_w ]
self.weights = [ w + v 
                for w, v in zip (self.weights, self.momentum_v)]
```

However, I'm getting following error:

```
 TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

for `momentum_v` update. My `eta` hyperparameter is already float although I again wrapped it by float function. I also wrapped `len(mini_batch)` by float as well. I also tried doing `nw.astype(float)` but I will still get the error. I am not sure why. `nabla_w` is a numpy array of floats.

Comment: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` does not happen when they are both numpy arrays. Something is a list or a tuple or some other sequence and *not* a numpy array. Print `type(variable)` for each variable being multiplied, and you'll see something isn't a numpy array. You didn't show your definitions of `momentum_mu` and `momentum_v`, perhaps they're the offenders? For e.g. see my answer from earlier today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520890/error-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float/47521032#47521032) from the same error message.

Comment: Also the error isn't telling you you *should* be using a `float`, it is telling you you're using a `float` where you *cannot*, so casting a bunch of things as `float` is not going to help resolve the issue. Somewhere you're multiplying a tuple or list by a float.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I see it now! I was initializing momentum_v wrong way, which was not a numpy array!. Thank you so much. You can write in the answer section and then I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, something is not a numpy array here. The error given above

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

is an error issued by Python for the sequence types (list, tuple, etc). The error message means that a sequence cannot be multiplied by a non-int. They *can* be multiplied by an int, but this doesn't change the values---it just repeats the sequence, i.e.,

```
>>> [1, 0] * 3
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

And of course in this frame, multiplying by a float makes no sense:

```
>>> [1, 0] * 3.14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

You'll see the same error message you've got here. So one of the variables you're multiplying is indeed not a numpy array and is one of the generic sequence types. A simple cast of `np.array()` around the offending variable would fix it, or of course you can just change the definition to an array.