# Error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code, when I try to run the line "x01 = rk4(x01,t1[-1],h1,fallParabola)," an error pops up saying "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'." I am wondering why this is, as I thought that multiplying every term in a numpy array by a number multiplied every term in the array by that number.

**slope1 and intercept1 are already defined elsewhere, so that is not an issue

```
def rk4(f,t,h,g):
    k1 = h*g(t,f)
    k2 = h*g(t+0.5*h, f+0.5*k1)
    k3 = h*g(t+0.5*h, f+0.5*k2)
    k4 = h*g(t+h, f+k3)
    return f + k1/6. + k2/3. + k3/3. + k4/6.

def fallParabola(t,f):
    g = 10
    px = f[0]
    py = f[1]
    vx = f[2]
    vy = f[3]
    slope = slope1 * (px-shift1)
    theta = sp.arctan(np.abs(slope))
    acc = np.array([vx,vy,g*sp.sin(theta)*sp.cos(theta), 
        g*sp.sin(theta)*sp.sin(theta)])
    return acc,slope

x01 = np.array([0.0,intercept1,0.0,0.0])
t01 = 0.
px1 = [x01[0],]
py1 = [x01[1],]
vx1 = [x01[2],]
vy1 = [x01[3],]
t1 = [t01,]
h1 = 0.1
while py1[-1] > 0:
    x01 = rk4(x01,t1[-1],h1,fallParabola)
    px1.append(x01[0])
    py1.append(x01[1])
    vx1.append(x01[2])
    vy1.append(x01[3])
    t1.append(t1[-1]+h1)
```

Comment: Change your code to something we can run. This, as presented, does not. Additionally, your are probably throwing away at least 50% of the info of that error-message (full stack-trace!).

Comment: ...see the [mcve] definition for more guidance on building the shortest possible code someone can use to see a problem themselves (and test prospective answers). This looks like something that should be reproducible in two lines, one of those an `import`, and the other a multiplication operation.

Comment: Sidenote: it looks you are multiplying a tuple (the return of fallParabola): ```h*g(t,f)```. But that's just a guess.

Comment: My guess that has encountered `alist*afloat`.  You are passing a list rather than array. `[1,2,3]*5` works, but not as if it were a array.

Answer (score 2):

You're multiplying `h` by a tuple, and not a numpy array in your Runge-Kutta definition:

```
def rk4(f,t,h,g):
    k1 = h*g(t,f)
    k2 = h*g(t+0.5*h, f+0.5*k1)
    k3 = h*g(t+0.5*h, f+0.5*k2)
    k4 = h*g(t+h, f+k3)
    return f + k1/6. + k2/3. + k3/3. + k4/6.
```

Here `g` is the function you're passing in, which is `fallParabola()` which by your definition returns a tuple:

```
def fallParabola(t,f):
    g = 10
    px = f[0]
    py = f[1]
    vx = f[2]
    vy = f[3]
    slope = slope1 * (px-shift1)
    theta = sp.arctan(np.abs(slope))
    acc = np.array([vx,vy,g*sp.sin(theta)*sp.cos(theta), 
        g*sp.sin(theta)*sp.sin(theta)])
    return acc,slope
```

You should modify this definition to return a numpy array so you can multiply through it:

```
return np.array([acc, slope])
```

---

The reason for the specific error message about non-int is simply because you *can* multiply a tuple by an integer, but this doesn't multiply the values inside the tuple. First, a tuple is immutable so you can't change the values anyways, but in general for sequences, multiplying by an integer repeats the sequence by the multiplier. For e.g.

```
>>> tup = (5, 4)
>>> tup*3
(5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4)
```

If you multiply here by a float, it doesn't make sense of course, and you get the same error you've got:

```
>>> tup*3.14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

---

Also as an aside, your `fallParabola()` function is not defined well IMO. Currently you have it taking global variables (like `slope1`, `shift1`) but it would be best to pass these values into the function. Generally global variables are not evil in Python, but if a function uses some parameters, it's best practice to send those parameters in so you know what it's using. And if you need to update the variables like `slope1` as time goes on, this provides an easier interface to do so.